# How can I prevent react-native-maps from crashing my app on screen touch with version 0.61.5 of react-native and 0.27.1 of react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, crash, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

**react-native-maps crashes app when touch on the screen**

```
react-native version : "0.61.5"
react-native-maps: "0.27.1"
```

1)I clean gradlew in android but not work
2)I gave the custom style property on MapView but not resolved
3)I also wrapped the MapView in an other Parent with style

```
style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  }}
but not work
```

4. I updated my react-native-maps version but other errors occured

Comment: hey man, with your question I think no one can help you.
please show log.